# Can't render object in Cycles!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have looked for answers, materials are all checked to render with camera icon, all layers visible, I can see objects in all modes, even render view, but not final render.

Tried brightening lights, turned off mist, background, environment in case they were obscuring.

A new object will render fine, just not my main object. It is UV mapped, and I made sure as per one suggestion that that was set in the appropriate box they mentioned. I am at my wits' end!!

[image]

Comment: Can't get your blend, use [this](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Your file is not available, always use the provided link for sharing files here

Comment: A link to a file that needs permission to download is not very useful...  You have to make things easier for those who want to help you. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to share your file. Also it is useful if you post images of your settings so that getting an answer does not depend exclusively on others downloading your file.

Comment: I think the permissions on Drive were set wrong, I set them to public. I will put them on the exchange.

Comment: Thanks! [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2180" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2180/)

Comment: As an aside, I got my texture from the UV wrapped image to turn into a "true" bump map in displacement, so I am assuming I should bake it in? I can't find a way to displace modify the small lines I drew myself, only vertices, but the true displace makes it look about the way I want.  When I try to bake, it says one material has an unconnected texture, and I can't find ANY textures in the nodes OR panels. This project is to help me learn, but I am more confused.

Comment: Okay, it shows up in render view, material view, and even OpenGL render and animation, but is all black in final cycles render.

Comment: OKAY, I experimented with a TON of settings, and somehow got it to work. I tried turning sequencing and compositing off and on, turning some AO checkboxes off and on, environment changes, and experimenting with scene and world nodes. For anyone else trying this, check those things and hopefully have some luck. The only problem now is that my bump/normal maps look good in material view, but move the whole faces in final render.

Comment: Updated file: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2181" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2181/)

Comment: update: I fixed the deformed faces by turning off object>auto smooth faces.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not rendering solid faces.  To fix this, go to *Properties* -> *Render Layers* and check *Use Surfaces*.

Comment: Thank you! I must have switched it on at some point in my experimenting, because I got it to work in the version above. Now my True Displacement shows up in material and render view, but not final. Once I have that solved, I will be golden.